# Decrypt pgp file in azure gen2 blob container

Tags: azure, azure-synapse, pgp

we are trying to decrypt PGP files pushed in our azure gen2 container. its encrypted using private key and we got both key and passphrase. we are using azure synapse analytics. I am looking if there is way to decrypt the file using PySpark code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Encrypt with private key? Are you sure?